# How can I return the input directly in java?

Tags: java

After user enter the number in the textfield and clicking on the button, I want to return the value in another textfield, I am not sure what class do I need for it, any hints please? thank you so much and here is my code:

```
private void newNumber(Container container){
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints constraint = new GridBagConstraints();
    //add the new number
    labelname = new JLabel("Enter the number: ");
    constraint.gridx = 0;
    constraint.gridy = 0;
    panel.add(labelname, constraint);

    number= new JTextField(10);
    constraint.gridx = 1;
    constraint.gridy = 0;
    panel.add(number, constraint);

    addnumber = new JButton("Add number");
    constraint.gridx = 0;
    constraint.gridy = 3;
    panel.add(addnumber, constraint);

    container.add(panel,"North");

}
```

I know it should have a method about ActionListener but I am still figuring it out :)

Comment: Please be clearer. We can't really understand what you're trying to accomplish here without further information.

Comment: Add actionlistener on your button and write the value of textField 1 on textfield2 under actionPerformed of Button

Comment: here you go: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

Answer (score 2):

Basically you assign the button an ActionListener in order to react to the click event. In this listener you get the value of the textfield and assign it to the other field.

```
JButton yourButton= new JButton("Click me");
JTextField textField = new JTextField("Some initial value Textfield 1");
JTextField textField2 = new JTextField("Some initial value Textfield 2");
yourButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    // Get value of textfield 1
     String currValue = textField.getText();
    // Set value for textfield 2
    textField2.setText(currValue); 
  }
});
```

Comment: if I separate my Java project to 3 classes: model, view and controller. I will put the JButton and JTextField in the view class, but where should I put the ActionListener, I'm struggling should I put it in both model and controller class...

Comment: @HuiTingKo I'd put it into the controller class. Maybe this helps to clarify things a bit: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/java-swing-mvc-example/

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FramTest extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        FramTest framTest = new FramTest();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        //add the new number
        JLabel labelname = new JLabel("Enter the number: ");
        panel.add(labelname);

        final JTextField number= new JTextField(10);

        panel.add(number);

        JButton addnumber = new JButton("Add number");
        panel.add(addnumber);

        final JTextField numberright= new JTextField(10);
        addnumber.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                numberright.setText(number.getText());

            }
        });

        panel.add(numberright);
        framTest.add(panel);

        framTest.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an ActionListener to your button, and in the listener you can add a call to a new method to perform the action you want. I am assuming you want to get the text from the textfield "number", and you want to write the value in a second textfield called "secondTextfield".

```
// Add the lister to the button
addnumber.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // Call a function to perform the action
        setTheText(evt);
    }
});

// Function to set the text
private void setTheText(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
     secondTextfield.set(number.getText());
}
```